# Zeroes of homogeneous polynomial on projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

Given a curve in projective $n$-space over an algebraically closed field and a homogeneous polynomial of degree $\geq 1$. Does it then always have a zero on the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the given curve, and $f$ the homogeneous polynomial, and consider the hypersurface $V = \{f = 0\}$. The general theorem about intersections of projective varieties is Bezout's theorem. But there are weaker statements that suffice in this situation. The following can be found in Hartshorne, *Algebraic geometry*, **Theorem I 7.2**:

> **Theorem** Let $Y, Z$ be varieties of dimensions $r,s$ in $\mathbb P^n$. If $r + s - n \geq 0$, then the intersection $Y \cap Z$ is nonempty.

In our situation, $r = \dim C = 1$ and $s = \dim V = n-1$, so $r + s - n = 0$, and hence $C \cap V$ is nonempty.